# "replace \ with \\ in python 3"

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to create a tiny script to list all files in a directory of some extension. Here the user will input the path to the directory on windows.

```
import os    
import fnmatch
DIRECTORY = "D:\Movies" 
EXTN = "*.mp4"  
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
# print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, EXTN):
            print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

I tried

```
DIRECTORY.replace('\', '\\')
print(DIRECTORY)
```

and i get an error like this
    DIRECTORY.replace('\', '\')
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
I am trying to auto convert the windows directory path to python 3 readable path and i have hit a wall. :(
update:
following works

```
DIRECTORY = r"D:\Movies"
```

but the same doesnt if the path is like this

```
DIRECTORY = r"D:\"
```

Comment: You don't need to replace the backslashes. What you do need to do is use raw strings: `DIRECTORY = r"D:\Movies"` (or use forward slashes instead of backslashes). In your case, the path was already valid because Python converts `\M` to `\\M` automatically, but if the character after the backslash happens to be part of an escape sequence, it will be converted (for example `C:\tmp` would become `C:<tab>mp`.

Comment: The user is inputting the path so they can't be relied to properly input the slashes

Comment: @Natecat: In that case, the backslashes are already properly escaped by `input()`.

Comment: @Natecat: The user's input slashes won't be interpreted as escapes in any event, so they wouldn't need fixing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't believe he is trying to escape backslashes, based on the fact he doesn't know how to escape them. He is trying to cleanse input.

Comment: @Natecat: Cleanse it of what?

Comment: @TimPietzcker 
`DIRECTORY = r"D:\Movies"`
works but
`DIRECTORY = r"D:\"`
i guess my problem is half solved. If the user inputs a directory then it works but if the user inputs a drive's root directory then it fails.

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi: If the path must end with a slash (only drive roots need this, otherwise `os.path.join` will stick together path components so none need to end with a backslash), you're stuck with non-raw strings, and double backslashing to escape (`"D:\\"`). But only on the literals in your code, what the user enters through `input` requires no escaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use raw strings in the first place, you don't need to replace (the extra slash you think you need is displayed for the `repr` to show the backslash was escaped, it's not actually part of the string).

For example `r'D:\Movies` has no risk of the backslash being misinterpreted (and if you show the `repr`, it will appear to have two slashes, but it makes it easier to type by using raw strings with just one).

And for anything `input` by the user, it's not a string literal, so backslash escapes aren't processed in the first place, they'd already be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters:

```
 DIRECTORY.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

Comment: No, you don't. That replace is too late, if the original single backslash was misinterpreted, there is no slash to replace in the first place, and making single backslashes into doubles just makes for a screwed up path.

Answer (score 0):

The character`\` is used to escape things that have significance outside of a string. What is happening here is the backslash is escaping the first quote meaning the last quote doesn't have a quote to end on this. To fix this, escape all the backslashes by doing this: `DIRECTORY.replace('\\', '\\\\')`

Comment: No, you don't. That replace is too late, if the original single backslash was misinterpreted, there is no slash to replace in the first place, and making single backslashes into doubles just makes for a screwed up path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but
`DIRECTORY = "D:\Movies" 
DIRECTORY.replace('\\', '\\\\')
print(DIRECTORY)`
result was
>>> (executing lines 1 to 3 of "<tmp 8>")
D:\Movies
so nothing changed.
>>> (executing lines 1 to 3 of "<tmp 8>")
D:\Movies

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi: You didn't assign the return value of the `replace`, so of course it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: replace doesn't work in place, you have to set DIRECTORY equal to the result of that function call